# How Wordpress hashes passwords

Tags: password, encryption

I found a nice [article](http://ttmm.io/tech/wordpress-password-hashing/) which explains at a high level how Wordpress hashes it's passwords, but is there a way to know exactly what encryption method from Portable PHP is used?

I am building a Wordpress site which will have member login. At some point in the future I need to supply these hashed passwords to another system and have the users log in there. I want to make sure that whatever method which the password gets passe through when logging in to compare with database value is available on this other system.

Comment: Instead of rolling your own implementation, why not just use WordPress's implementation?

Comment: I am using Wordpress for the time being, but it eventually has to be migrated to another system. I want to make sure migration is possible. This is a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of the linked article (thanks for the shout-out, by the way).

The WordPress function that does the hashing is `wp_has_password()` and, by default, it will run the password through 8 rounds whatever the "best" algorithm the server makes available to PHPass is. WordPress, again by default, uses MD5. However you can also configure things to use Blowfish or DES if you so desire.

For reference, take a look at:

- [`wp_hash_password()`'s implementation](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2001) in `pluggable.php`
- [Phpass's `PasswordHash` class](https://github.com/hautelook/phpass/blob/master/src/Hautelook/Phpass/PasswordHash.php) itself

Note [the documentation of `wp_hash_password` itself](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) states:

> Creates a hash of a plain text password. Unless the global $wp_hasher is set, the default implementation uses PasswordHash, which adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5. MD5 is used by default because it's supported on all platforms. You can configure PasswordHash to use Blowfish or extended DES (if available) instead of MD5 with the $portable_hashes constructor argument or property (see examples).

If you're still in PHP land, you can port the functionality *directly* to your new system and have a fair amount of parity with WordPress' default implementation. You could also just build the new system in such a way that it uses WordPress as the authentication provider (similar to OpenID), then you won't need to worry about it at all.